# What are the practical benefits of LISP like syntax which Clojure uses over Java like syntax of Scala?

Tags: scala, lisp, clojure

I spent couple of months learning Scala and got overwhelmed by number of different constructs it had,
After looking at partial functions, partially-applied functions, pattern matching, actor syntax,
I gave a thought to learning Clojure which doesn't have too much in  terms of syntax but looking at the how Java inter-operability is handled, it looks very difficult to get use to.

for example: things like `doto, new and .`

Every time I start typing a function, there are times I write `(1 + 2)` instead of `(+ 1 2).`

It looks like I will have to completely forget how I write regular programs to get use to this syntax.

Also finding it difficult to deal with side-effects that do and let form have.
Aren't they similar to what functions with void type are ?

Things like registering a callback,things normal I/O, how can such things be side-effects free.

Till now all I really liked about Functional Programming is that,
immutability makes concurrency easier when dealing with shared data,
functions as first class objects and having higher-order functions,
apply,map and reduce with functions and lists
.

I wanted to know, are there practical benefits I will get once I am use to this syntax ?
I f I continue to learn Scala and avoid using var, and always use recursion instead of loops.
I can do all the above things and still write understandable code.

Comment: The difference between infix (1 + 2) and prefix (+ 1 2) notation has absolutely nothing to do with *functional* vs. *imperative*.

Comment: ya.. typed that in a hurry. edited my post.

Comment: Lisp is a very simple language. It is by far easier to write parsers for LISP than for e.g. Java or Scala. So the prefix notation was chosen because of its simplicity *despite its inconvenience*. Getting used to this syntax won't buy you much.

Comment: Getting used to prefix (+ 1 2) notation means you can define macros. Paul Graham's _On Lisp_ explains the benefits of macros in great detail.

Comment: Answer to the title of your question: [Homoiconicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity).

Comment: No.  Homoiconicity is orthogonal to concrete syntax.  It's about abstract syntax, and how code is represented and evaluated.  There are Lisps which are not homoiconic (I've written one myself), and non-Lisps which are homoiconic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Lisp syntax is just that:  syntax.  It has nothing to do with semantics.  In other words, the syntax (ideally) shouldn't affect how you write programs; if you feel like you have to "completely forget how you write regular programs", it sounds like you're having difficulty with the semantics, not with the syntax.

Practical benefits of Lisp syntax include:

- consistency.  Function/macro/special-form followed by its arguments.  No operator precedence issues.  Grouping is usually explicit.
- easy to parse and unparse.  This makes it easier to write source code tools, such as static analyzers and code browsers.
- extensibility

  - user-defined macros.  Users can extend their Lisp system's syntax.
  - system-defined syntax.  New special forms can be added to a Lisp system without having to worry about how their syntax interferes with existing forms.

You also threw in a couple of questions about side effects and functional programming.  Those aren't related to Lisp syntax and should really be asked in a separate question.

Comment: How do people dry run such code?
I mean expression inside expression  inside expression.

by the time you solve inner expression you forget what the other one was ? and if remember as well it's difficult to identify which close paren si for which open paren?
Should every new '(' be in a new level of indentation ?
Any tips ?

Comment: @Amogh In my limited experience with Clojure, yes, you want to use a newline and indent for nested functions. This is a Y-Combinator example I adapted from a tutorial in Scheme to Clojure that shows how I'd lay it out:  http://www.pasteall.org/41052/lisp

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar the only way to get good at it is to do it and look at how other top coders do it.  There's no magic trick.  Parentheses matching isn't a problem if you have any kind of code-aware text editor at all.

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar: Dry-running code is just a matter of running it in the REPL (read-evaluate-print loop (an interactive command-line-like environment, like irb for ruby)).  You can copy-paste from the editor to the REPL, and it doesn't have to be a whole function, it can be a subexpression that you're testing.  Modularity helps with testing, so if you feel that the function is too big and needs to be broken into subfunctions, you're probably right.  Using "let" also helps avoid too much nesting, since you can define helper functions.

Comment: wrote a function tat returns a vector containing fibonacci numbers with n elements.

feel much better now :)

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar. Your eyes use the indentation to tell what is what, rather than jumping back and forth matching parens.

Comment: I've also found it easier to read Lisp style syntax from the "inside out". You're probably use to imperative style programming where you just read from top to bottom and get an idea of what's going on. Lisp tends to be easier to understand if you start from the "innermost" set of parenthesis and work your way out, at least for me anyway.

Comment: @mike30: I also use this trick: I look at the indentation and forget about the parens. BTW, isn't this the same trick we use to read C code (C++, Java, C#, ...)?

Answer (score 9):

## Syntax

The syntax threw me off too at first, but after working with it and reading about it I realized some things:

**1. Lisp doesn't have operators, it only has functions,** so stop thinking of `+-*/` as operators and that will help with things.

Don't think:

```
(1 + 2 + 3 + 4)
```

or, even though it's correct:

```
(+  1 2 3 4)
```

but:

```
(sum  1 2 3 4)
```

and it will feel more natural.

Likewise with `-`, think more along the lines of:

```
(subtract-from  x  y1 y2 y3)
```

and that should help.

**2. Method calls aren't that different!**

Functions are the first thing in every Lisp form (the stuff between the `()`); since methods are functions, they come first! It's not really *that* different from Java's syntax though -- all you're doing is moving the starting paren to the front and swapping the positions of the object and method:

Java:

```
objectInstance.someMethod(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

Clojure:

```
(.someMethod objectInstance arg1 arg2 arg3)
```

(You also lose the commas and semicolon!)

The `(.someMethod objectInstance ...)` is a special form that gets expanded out into a form using `.`: `(. objectInstance someMethod ...)`. The latter feels weird because we're not used to thinking of the `.` as actually doing something when we're calling a method/property in Java; the former is the idiomatic way of doing things in Clojure anyway ([reference](http://clojure.org/java_interop)).

New is similar:

```
new namespace.Object(); // Java

(new namespace.Object)  ; Clojure
```

## "Difficult Things"

The "difficult things" you mentioned are actually there to make your life easier!!

You said in a comment that it was annoying to keep track of things when nesting expressions within expressions; the `do` and `let` forms are built specifically to help ease that difficulty.

**Let's start with `do`**

`do` lets you call things imperatively, one after another, without nesting:

```
(do (.someMethod objectInstance arg1 arg2)
    (.someOtherMethod objectInstance "foo" "bar" "baz")
    (.aMethod anotherObjectInstance 0))
```

The behavior of `do` is such that each of these method calls will be run in the order in which they're given and the return result of the last expression (in this case the return result of `(.aMethod anotherObjectInstance 0)`) is what is returned from the `do` block itself.

Each of these methods may or may not have side effects, and may or may not return a value (all of which but the last will be ignored).

**Let**

The `let` form does the same thing as `do` but it also gives you the ability to add local variables to the mix:

```
(let [foo "foo"
      bar "bar"
      arg1 (generateValueFrom foo)
      arg2 (generateValueFrom bar)]
  (.someMethod objectInstance arg1 arg2)
  (.someOtherMethod objectInstance foo bar "baz")
  (.aMethod anotherObjectInstance 0))
```

Again, the method calls will be run step by step in order, only this time they use the local variables defined in the `let`'s bindings (the stuff between the `[]`), and the last call's return value will be returned as the `let`'s return value.

`let` is handy for breaking a bunch of nested calls down into something more sane; e.g.:

```
(reduce someCombiner {} (filter keepXs (map someTransform ys)))
```

becomes:

```
(let [txd (map someTransform ys)
      xs  (filter keepXs txd)]
  ; do the last call in the let's body so that
  ; its return value is what gets returned
  (reduce someCombiner {} xs))
```

## Is The Synatx Worth It?

You bet your sweet bippy it is!

The Lisp syntax allows the language to have macros. Macros are functions that run at compile time that rewrite the code. What this means is that you can take code that is repetitititve or complex and write a macro that is simpler to call, and that macro will write the complex version for you.

For example, say we have the following `do` block:

```
(do (.someMethod      objectInstance arg1 arg2)
    (.aSillyMethod    objectInstance "foo" "bar" "baz")
    (.aSadMethod      objectInstance "alpha")
    (.anHappyMethod   objectInstance 1 2 3)
    (.someOtherMethod objectInstance \a \b \c)
    (.aMethod         objectInstance 0))
```

We have to repeat the same object instance six times! That's annoying. The `doto` macro can make things a bit lighter for us typing-wise:

```
(doto objectInstance
  (.someMethod      arg1 arg2)
  (.aSillyMethod    "foo" "bar" "baz")
  (.aSadMethod      "alpha")
  (.anHappyMethod   1 2 3)
  (.someOtherMethod \a \b \c)
  (.aMethod         0))
```

The `doto` macro allows us to specify the object instance *once*, up front, instead of having to repeat ourselves in the code later on -- it rewrites the expressions we give into the `do` block shown above. (This particular macro is similar to the `with` syntax some languages support.)

Now, this is a really simple example, but just imagine what sorts of coding tasks you could automate! And that's where the power of Lisp's macros comes in: you can write functions to make the programming language write your code for you!

## Side Effects

You can still have side-effects in Clojure code, especially if you're doing interop with Java OOP since that OOP has side-effects. If you use more of the core Clojure code than Java, you'll not have as many side effects because it'll be more purely functional.

A lot of what I've found in my functional programming experience is that it's about partitioning the side-effect causing code from the purely functional code. You can do this in pretty much whatever language you're using (even Java).

## Comparison to Scala

I've not used Scala, so I can't help you there. But hopefully the above was informative.

Comment: You can partition the side-effect code in Java, but it's not very idiomatic.

Comment: @tieTYT Right, since with OOP you have little bundles of state all over the place. You can use stuff like [Command-Query Separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation) though to help know when you will cause side effects.

Answer (score 2):

These are matter of taste. I have converted gradually over the years to preferring Lisp syntax over Java syntax. Why? Good question. Can't really pinpoint a single reason, but here are some thoughts.

Lisp syntax is very simple, almost trivial, albeit maybe bit strange at first (before you unlearn some old habits). Trivial syntax makes it easy to programmatically mangle Lisp code. Code is data is code. Make macros and DSL way more easier and effective. "Lisp is a programmable programming language."

This gets bit philosphical, but I strongly feel that Lisp syntax is closer to "true nature of programs". Structure of programs is not linear -- it's more tree/network like. Java point of view is more linear, line oriented. Lisp POV is hierarcial and tree oriented. Those parenthesis inside paranthesis is just a way to write trees.

Thinking more in tree oriented (rather than line oriented) way enables new ways of thinking, editing and working with code. For example some powerfull tools such as [Paredit](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/PareditCheatsheet), which demonstrates some concepts which might not make much sense in Java syntax, such as *barf* and *slurp*:

```
slurp:
(foo (bar |baz) quux zot) -->  (foo (bar |baz quux) zot)

barf:
(foo (bar |baz quux) zot) -->  (foo (bar |baz) quux zot)
```

Code is a tree! :)

Answer (score 0):

The principles of the functional language like lisp or clojure are very useful for writing self modifing code.

So for adding some values you have only to generate a instruction with a + at the beginning and the numbers after that, in an imperative language you have to add each additional value manually.

The thing is, languages like lisp or clojure don't really have any syntax, ist only a description of a tree structure as text.

Comment: Yes, Lisps do have syntax in multiple forms: 1) numbers, strings, symbols, lists, etc.; 2) special form syntax -- such as `define <symbol> <form>` or `lambda <parameter list> <body forms>`; 3) macro syntax, both reader macros and the other kind; 4) syntax extensions such as Clojure uses, i.e. `[...]` for vectors, `{...}` for object literals, etc.  So it's really false advertising to say that Lisps are syntax-free.

Comment: The fact that lisp is functional has nothing to do with the self modifying code trick. Besides, Lisp is not a functional language.

Comment: @MattFenwick: is there any advantage of quoted list over vectors ?

Comment: @FlorianMargaine LISP is not a functional language? I'm sorry, but whaaaaa? A language developed to be the programmatic form of lambda calculus and you're saying it's not functional? How do you figure?

Comment: @JimmyHoffa Lisp is as procedural as it can get. If any language with first-class functions is "functional", then C is one too (thanks to function pointers). And Lisp is just as functional as C.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine I was referring to the mathematical definition for functional as it is based on math. But if you go the technical definition; I would say having arbitrary depth lexical closures is a pretty strong indicator of a functional language, which C doesn't have. As per wikipedia though "Functional Programming" refers to being rooted in math: "In computer science, functional programming is a programming paradigm that treats computation as the evaluation of mathematical functions" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming

Comment: "... and avoids state and mutable data." <- Which is pretty much what defines functional languages. Lisp is everything but side-effect free.

Comment: Alright, "Lisp is as functional as C" was an exageration. However, it is still true that Lisp is far from being a functional language, because it mutates data and uses states all the time. And also because you usually write Lisp in a procedural way.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine if you say purity is a requirement of functional programming, then you're saying ML isn't a functional language either...

Comment: @JimmyHoffa according to Wikipedia's definition, purity is a *requirement*. "avoids state and mutable data" means exactly that.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Wikipedia page for LISP and ML both list functional in their paradigm too... And are you really going to claim ML isn't a functional language? LISP and ML are the basis for the most common types of functional languages. In your definition other than Haskell derivatives, Erlang and esoterics, there are no functional languages...

Comment: I mean, come on, read the Wikipedia's definition. "It emphasizes the application of functions, in contrast to the imperative programming style, which emphasizes changes in state." Lisp uses state all the time. What more do you need? And I'm going to edit wikipedia's page about Lisp, since this is false. Most recognized Lisp hackers agree that Lisp isn't a functional language.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa Lisp is, in general, not a "pure functional language". It encourages 9and makes it relatively easy) to write code in a functional style, but provides (specifically in Common Lisp, but probably in other languages in the family) a wide variety of imperative tools to use when that makes expressing your code easier.

Comment: Lisp is a multi paradigm language, sort of like C++. It allows you to write procedural code, OOP code, functional code (C++ allows this to an extent), etc. Lisp is definitely not pure-functional, but it offers tools to write code in a functional style should you choose to.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Lisp was the first functional language. What you want to say is that Lisp is not only functional, but it very much is functional. In Lisp, you actually can not write imperative code without a macro. Expressions take inputs and return values. Procedures do not need to return value, can be void. This is a big difference. Where Lisp also allows imperative programming is in that functions can get input from other places than their arguments. In C, a function pointer does not have to return a value, it is only a controlled goto.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Let me be more specific. Lisp was the first language to provide all the necessary constructs to enable a functional style of programming. Lisp predates C. Lisp was also the first dynamic language. Lisp was never exclusively functional, it also provided constructs that enabled imperative and procedural programming, and later OOP and constraint programming. Most functional languages are not purely functional, you can still use them to code in a functional style. Clojure is more functional than Common Lisp, but still not pure. Purity is about what you can't do, not what you can.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Since when are functions threated as first class citizen in C(++)? You can't pass functions around and modify them like in a functional language (FP). You just can pass pointer at the functions around (_big_ difference), to modify the function you need to write another functions and call the callee, thats not functional programming. Likewise you can't store without dirty hacks a list of functions into an array or hashmap (like variables).

Comment: @Quonux http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/193864/what-are-the-practical-benefits-of-lisp-like-syntax-which-clojure-uses-over-java/193868?noredirect=1#comment374502_193868

Comment: so what, functional languages don't have to be pure languages...Functional languages are called as such because functions are first class citizens, point.